# How to have auth.loggedIn before rendering in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

The `/api/user/` request to make `$auth.loggedIn` available happens after client already loads/started loading. This makes some of my modules render and then disappear after `$auth.loggedIn` has turned true/false, making everything look messy on page load.

It would be ideal if the call to `/api/user/` happened in the same way an asyncData request works so that `$auth.loggedIn` is available before anything renders. Is there any setup/config that makes this possible ? I'm using the universal mode.

Comment: You could look into lifecycle hooks to get the right direction - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

You can use the middleware defined in Nuxt [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware)
In your case you could do your request on `/api/user` before like that, in a middleware called `userLoggedIn` for example.

```
export default function (context) {
    // Here we return a Promise in the middleware to make it asynchronous
    // Cf doc https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware
    // So we return a promise that can only be resolved when the function resolve is called
    return new Promise(resolve => this.$axios.$get('/api/user'/).then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            console.log('NOT LOGGED');
            // Do something if not logged, like redirect to /login
            return context.redirect('/login');
        }
        resolve(user);
    }));
}
```

I made a proposition with $axios but of course you can change it. You just need to keep the middleware and the promise to have an asynchronous middleware.

Then on your page waiting for the query, you can add:

```
export default {
    middleware: [
        'userLogged',
    ],
    data() {...}
};
```